# Get the percentage of a number

Tags: c#, math, percentage

I have a question related to percentage calculations:

In the following image is an example of two segments:
[image]

The first segment X has the min value 2,5 and max value 12,7
The second segment Y has min value 0,75 and max value 5,4

I need to calculate in C# what percentage is Y max value (5,4) from X min and X max?

Something like this i need: in the range from 0 to 49 -> value 10 is (10 / 49) * 100 = 20,40816326530612.

How can i calculate in C# what is the percentage of 5,4 in the range 2,5 - 12,7 ?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your best C# attempt and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @Richard Do you need to ask that? I think it's pretty obvious. :)

Comment: This is a maths question, not a programming question, so off topic.

Comment: The answer is approximately 28.431372549019607843137254901961%

Comment: The problem was in my C# code, calculation was done with wrong number formatting ...

Comment: @Chamster Well it *should* be obvious; but, repeatedly, it clearly isn't. :-(

Answer (score 3):

this has nothing to do with C# but with Maths ;)

What if you change the scale to start at 0 instead of 2.5:

12.7-2.5 = 10.2
5.4-2.5 = 2.9

(2.9/10.2)*100 is your answer.

the full calculation would be:

(value - minY)/(maxX - minY) * 100.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer the problem was actually not in the math calculations but in the way I was displaying it. Wrong format, the number was rounded therefore was wrong than with another calculation I was getting a completely wrong result because I did it on paper and was correct ... my mistake in the c# code.

Comment: why do you need to divide by 100?

Comment: multiply sorry. I change the answer